# TCPDF - How to display tableheaders on each page of table data?

Tags: php, tcpdf

All,

I am trying to render a table with pages and pages of data. The rendering fails utterly from the second page onwards. Also, how can I make sure the table that extends over pages and pages has tableheaders on each and every page?

This is the function I am using so far, but it doesn't seem to work very nicely from second page onwards:

Thanks

```
// Colored table
public function ColoredTable($header,$data) {
    // Colors, line width and bold font
    $this->SetFillColor(170,195,255);
    $this->SetTextColor(0);
    $this->SetDrawColor(205, 205, 205);
    $this->SetLineWidth(0.3);
    $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'B');
    // Header
    $w = array(35, 35, 20, 20, 20, 10, 20, 8, 20);
    $num_headers = count($header);
    for($i = 0; $i < $num_headers; ++$i) {
        $this->Cell($w[$i], 7, $header[$i], 1, 0, 'C', 1);
    }
    $this->Ln();
    // Color and font restoration
    $this->SetFillColor(225, 229, 233);
    $this->SetTextColor(0);
    $this->SetFont('helvetica','','10');
    // Data
    $fill = 0;
    foreach($data as $row) {

        $this->MultiCell($w[0], 8, $row[0], 1, 'L', $fill, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 8, 'M', true);
        $this->MultiCell($w[1], 8, $row[1], 1, 'L', $fill, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 8, 'M', true);
        $this->MultiCell($w[2], 5, $row[2], 1, 'L', $fill, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 10, 'M', true);
        $this->MultiCell($w[3], 5, $row[3], 1, 'L', $fill, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 10, 'M', true);
        $this->MultiCell($w[4], 8, $row[4], 1, 'L', $fill, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 8, 'M', true);
        $this->MultiCell($w[5], 5, $row[5], 1, 'L', $fill, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 10, 'M', true);
        $this->MultiCell($w[6], 8, $row[6], 1, 'L', $fill, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 8, 'M', true);
        $this->MultiCell($w[7], 5, $row[7], 1, 'L', $fill, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 10, 'M', true);
        $this->MultiCell($w[8], 8, $row[8], 1, 'L', $fill, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 8, 'M', true);
        $this->Ln();
        $fill=!$fill;
    }
    $this->Cell(array_sum($w), 0, '', 'T');
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The following code might work:

```
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, 300, "", PDF_HEADER_STRING);
```